# codeigniter how to send query->num_rows from model to controler

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, variable-assignment

Perhaps a simple question:

This is my striped code in my model:

```
    public function trainees()
{        
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('relations');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() >0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

My controler:

```
    public function adresslist() {
    $this->load->model('Adresslist');
    $data['trainees'] = $this->Adresslist->trainees();
    $data['numrows'] =  ??????
    $this->load->view('adresslist', $data);        
}
```

And in my view I load the table data with a foreach
works perfect.

But how do I send the value of num_rows to my controler?

Comment: have you tried using `$query->result_array();` ?

Comment: `count($data['trainees'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of trainees is simply the length of the array returned, you don't need to know num_rows

```
$data['numrows'] = count( $data['trainees']);
```

will do the trick